# if $ \beta $ is one to one then $\alpha$ and $ \beta $ have inverses and are inverses to one another

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the mappings

$ \alpha : A \rightarrow B$ ,
$ \beta : B \rightarrow C$

Where $\beta \alpha = 1_{A}$

How would one go about proving if $ \beta $ is one to one then $\alpha$ and $ \beta $ have inverses and are inverses to one another.

My issue here is just showing that the inverse exists. Showing that they are inverses to each other i understand

Answer (score 0):

What you want to show is that $\alpha \beta = 1_B$. So, since $\beta$ is injective, this is the same thing as asking $\beta \alpha \beta = \beta$ (if $h$ is injective, then $f = g$ if and only if $hf = hg$. Prove this formally if you need to). But we can simplify the LHS to the RHS because of our assumption $\beta \alpha = 1_A$.